# Two actions form

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a simple member subscription form on a site and would like to somehow make it not only subscribe users to the site but also add their email to my mailchimp list.
So, basically my form has its "action" now and I have another action URL for mailchimp with my ID and all.
I was wondering if it is possible that when user clicks on submit button they become a member (form makes the action 1) and at the same time their email forwards to mailchimp list (transfering the value from only that input field to action 2).

Hope it's somehow possible through javascript or something like that as I don't have much control over form's php.

Comment: Too much to read, code samples make ques interesting, Just giving what you have to do isn't going to lead anywhere. :)

Comment: you don't need to have 2 forms handlers.. the code that handle the subscription can also handle the mailing list.

Comment: Ok, what i have now is
<form action="http://app.xyz.net/signup.cfm" method="post" id="signup" class="signup-form" onsubmit="_gaq.push(['_linkByPost', this]);">
and various input fields in the form (first, last name, email, password..)
I would like that clicking on submit button does what it does now, but ALSO using the "email' input value takes the action "<form action="http://xyz.us1.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post?u=xyz;id=xyz">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the mailchimp action does not give a response (or at least it is not important to you). Then you might use a jQuery ajax post for this, triggered when you submit the form:

```
//prepare action 2 (mailchimp) with any form fields that should be sent there
objPostParameters = [];
objPostParameters["firstfield"] = fieldvalue;
...other post parameters...

//send action 2, including any get parameters and the above prepared post parameters (if needed)
$.post( "/mailchimp.php?getparameters...", objPostParameters );

//submit the form to action 1 (subscribe)
document.yourformname.submit();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Markus. Though I am still confused about how to apply it to what i got. It's 
<form action="app.xyz.net/signup.cfm"; method="post" id="signup" class="signup-form" onsubmit="_gaq.push(['_linkByPost', this]);"> and various input fields in the form (first, last name, email, password..) I would like that clicking on submit button does what it does now, but also ONLY using the "email' input value takes the action "<form action="xyz.us1.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post?u=xyz;id=xyz">

I would really appreciate if you could help further though i am thankful for your help already

Comment: You could add only the email input to the PostParameters. Make sure the name of the field is exactly the same that is uses by mailchimp. `objPostParameters["exact_name_of_the_email_field_for_mailchimp"] = $("input[name=youremailfieldname]").val();`, then post it to `xyz.us1.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post?u=xyz;id=xyz`. That should be all.

Comment: Ok, if i understood well, I could leave the first action inside my opening form tag, and omit the last part of your script (document.myformname.submit)? so that it's <form action="action1">
and then just add this script
<script>
objPostParameters = [];
objPostParameters["mce-EMAIL"] = $("input[name=mce-EMAIL]").val();
$.post( "xyz.us1.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post?u=xyz;id=xyz"", objPostParameters );
</script>

Comment: Mostly. Leave the first action inside the opening form tag. Build a function containing the javascript code. `function funcSendToMailchimp() { objPostParameters = []; objPostParameters["mce-EMAIL"] = $("input[name='mce-EMAIL']").val(); $.post( "xyz.us1.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post?u=xyz;id=xyz", objPostParameters ); }` And call the function upon form submit.

Comment: Me again, it's not working :(
this is the exact code i have:
in the head of the document i have this:
<script>
function funcSendToMailchimp() 
{
objPostParameters = []; objPostParameters["EMAIL"] = $("input[name='EMAIL']").val(); $.post("http://xyz.us6.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post?u=ef38426360b899d65e3afae24&amp;id=ad04c47ffd", objPostParameters);
}
</script>
and form goes like this:
<form action="http://members.xyz.com/signup.cfm" method="post" id="signup" class="signup-form" onsubmit="funcSendToMailchimp();" autocomplete="on">
email input has the id "mce-EMAIL" and name "EMAIL"

Comment: It should be `objPostParameters['mce-EMAIL']`, everything else seems correct at first sight